# Additional spaces displayed differently in markdown and rendered output diff

Tags: feature-request, markdown, markdown-rendering, diff

When removing one of two consecutive spaces, [like here before the word "declaring"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8850705), rendered-output-diff highlights the entire subsequent word "declaring", whereas the markdown-diff more accurately just shows the deletion of that single space.

Proposal: change the rendered-output-diff to a more compact display similar to markdown-diff.