# Markdown and rendered changes are very different in edit review queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits, user-interface

When reviewing suggested edits, the markdown version and rendered version can show different changes, particularly block-indenting of code. More specifically, it's possible for the *markdown* version to omit certain changes. For example, in [this edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13150302), the markdown looks like this:

[image]

but the rendered version looks like this:

[image]

These are very different. I was double-checking some recent reviews and thought that the markdown correctly reflected all that had changed, that is, some trivial (and mostly incorrect) use of inline-code formatting. I therefore thought certain users had performed bad reviews, when in fact they had not.

**This is a bug.** Some changes will inevitably be invisible in the rendered output, but the markdown should always show all changes, especially significant formatting improvements.

Note: I don't think this is a duplicate. Similar questions have been asked before (for example: [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299633/additional-spaces-displayed-differently-in-markdown-and-rendered-output-diff), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312604/rendered-output-and-markdown-views-in-suggested-edits), and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322177/markdown-rendering-issue-in-suggested-edit-review)), but they aren't the same. Most of the time, people are pointing out that the *rendered* view doesn't display all changes. I haven't found anywhere that someone has pointed out that the *markdown* is omitting changes (and gotten an answer).

Can we fix this?

Comment: Do you suppose this issue is restricted to SO? Else it would make sense to post the question to meta SE, wouldn't it?

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330573/6083675) I just asked about Docs.

Comment: @guntbert [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them). If you want the Meta EXP, report on mSE; if not, here works. ;)

Comment: @guntbert It's almost certainly a network-wide issue, though it's only likely to come up on certain sites. Some SE sites don't really make much use of code formatting, so bugs there wouldn't necessarily matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Technically* there's no bug in the markdown diff view. It is accurately showing that a blank line was added between the non-indented lines and the indented lines, and that's what caused the rendering change (indented lines after non-indented lines don't get rendered as code unless there's at least one blank line in between).

Perhaps the SO markdown parser should be changed to handle this differently, but that's another request.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I was thinking it was the indenting that changed, but you're right that it's only a line addition. (It has been a long day.) I do think that needs to be made much more clear, but I have to agree it's not technically a bug. I'm accepting this answer and will try to rewrite this into a feature request (as a new question, of course).

Comment: @EdCottrell it may be a change bought about by the commonmark implementation, as before that it was ambiguous if the new line before a code block was necessary.

Comment: It could be nice to display a grey "carriage return" symbol like U+23CE (⏎) or U+21B5 (↵) to make the new line more visible.