# Markdown view does not show white space diffs

Tags: bug, documentation, markdown

In [Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/74240), markdown view is broken when it comes to showing changes in indentation:

[image: xml highlighting] > [image: more than highlights]

In this case, it appears like the only change was adding XML highlighting, but that's not the case. It also indented some code that was previously being stripped automatically.

None of the preceding white space is shown for anything in Docs, it seems.

<s>I think it might be related to this [other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330549/6083675), but that question did not mention Docs.</s> Wait... new evidence changes things:

I have confirmed that it fails to show when newlines are added, but the issue extends beyond that. As proof, I made an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/76720) to some random Documentation, which originally looked like this:

> [image: Docs]

There are two significant lines here: one that needs a new line and indentation and another that just needs indentation.

I made some changes. Here are the two diff modes:

[image: Markdown] > [image: Rendered]

I'll note two things here:

1. You cannot see that ANYTHING is indented as code from Markdown view
2. You can't see that I added a newline, but you can see that if there was an existing new line, there is a newline in the diff.

If you weren't frustrated already, imagine reviewing this (red freehand added for ease of locating the code):

> [image: Python]

If you are familiar with Python, even a tiny bit, you know how important indentation is. Without the indentation and new lines, the code will not run. The above Python edit got approved, however. You may wonder why, but it should be more obvious looking at the other view:

> [image: Other view]

Comment: Yup, it's busted in Docs. Viewing the source, it looks like the whites pace is present but maybe not styled/tagged correctly to get it to be visible.

Comment: I nearly rejected a proposed change because code was not marked a such, making the example very confusing and unhelpful. Luckily I decided to check the non-markdown version, too, and saw that it was alright. (I usually find the Markdown diffs easier to read but as it is, they are unusable.)